# How to get name of selected image?

Tags: windows-phone-7

My problem is, when we attach images in any email, the attachment has its picture name like "`WP_2761.png`" etc. But when we try from `PhotoChooserTask` it has its temporary name like "`PhotoChooser bla bla.jpg`". Can we retrieve name like in email clients ?

Comment: Are you using `e.OriginalFileName` ?

Comment: yes I'm using `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.OriginalFileName);`

Comment: can you show some code to demonstrate the issue, please?

Comment: In `photoChooserTask`'s callback, I've written above code. That's what I did till yet.